# Merge property values of 2 objects into an array using underscore chain

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following:

```
a = {x:1, y:3, w:4}
b = {c:2, d:3}
```

And I want to obtain all the values of these objects iterating only once.

```
result = [1, 3, 4, 2, 3]
```

I have the following solution but it has multiple iterations.

```
result = _.chain(a).values().union(_.values(b)).value();
```

I would like to avoid the "_.values(b)" and do this using the same chain from a.

I also tried this, but it is not working properly:

```
result = _.chain({}).extend(a,b).values().value();
```

Comment: What you have is the best solution you can find I guess.

Comment: You could merge the objects, then get the values from the merged object.

Comment: @torazaburo That will not work if the objects have keys in common, right

Comment: @luis No, it won't, but you yourself showed a similar approach in your last code fragment (which works for me...why do you say "it is not working properly"?).

Comment: The problem comes when you have common keys between the 2 objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're intent on chaining, then

```
_.chain([a, b])   .         // [ { x: 1, y: 3, w: 4 }, { c: 2, d: 3 } ]
    map(_.values) .         // [ [    1,    3,    4 ], [    2,    3 ] ]
    flatten()     .         // [      1,    3,    4,        2,    3   ]
    uniq()        .         // [      1,    3,    4,        2         ]
    value()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about.

```
var a = {x:1, y:3, w:4},
    b = {c:2, d:3};

result = _.values(_.extend(a,b));
```

Comment: Weird, I always get the same result. https://jsfiddle.net/jrmh35js/

Are you changing the input?

Comment: @GusOrtiz What if both the objects have same keys?

Comment: right that's the issue.. it's fine though, i can make my keys unique for my solution. thanks! is having _.chain({}).extend(a,b).values() any different than your solution? I thought the chain one was faster

Comment: Well I updated the fiddle adding the chain one, and timed them both. They usually end in the same time, but we´d need a lot of data to make a better benchmark.
I don´t know the internals of underscore, so I wouldn't know which one is faster.
https://jsfiddle.net/jrmh35js/1/ Theres the updated fiddle.